# How to maintain resolution or increase resolution of image in laravel 6 in php

Tags: php, laravel-6

I am try to make an image of idcard but when i changed its size its resolution get down i want to maintain size  88mm x 58 mm(1043 x 677 px),
when I resize it using image intervention it get's down to 88mm x 58mm(219 x 332 px)which is very low,
and if increased the px the 88 x 58 mm height width get distributed so it can occur error,

means i want to change height and width, but while keeping mm lengths same and increase only height

I've tried this,

```
$card_width = $request->width * 3.779; //assume it is comming 57(mm)
$card_height = $request->height * 3.779; //assume it is comming 88(mm)
$img = Image::make($request->design_img)->resize($card_width, $card_height)->encode('png');
$temp_data_f = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($temp_data_f);
```

Above code gives me 48kb file with very low resolution of image which have distrubed my printing quality,
actually the uploaded file was of size 88 x 58 mm(1043 x 677 px),
after code get same size but 88 x 58 mm (219 x 332 px),

i want to keep mm to be same and only increse px,
Also i don't want to compress image,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey i got the answer my self,

```
$card_width = $request->card_width * 12;
          $card_height = $request->card_height * 12;

          $temp_data_f = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->card_template_f));
          $temp_data_f = Image::make($temp_data_f)->resize($card_width, $card_height)->encode('png');
          $img_f = new \Imagick();
          $img_f->readImageBlob($temp_data_f);
          $img_f->setImageResolution(118.111,118.111);
          $img_f->setImageFormat("png");
          $blob_f = $img_f->getImageBlob();
          $temp_data_f = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($blob_f);
```

this will get any resolution image but will output base64 300 resolution image 
if you want to change resolution just change
`$img_f->setImageResolution(118.111,118.111);`change `118.111` to desired value as 
`desired_resolution/2.54 = value` just replace value with 118.111